# Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Apex Classes

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I'm trying to install a MANAGED PACKAGE from my developer org to TRIAL Professional Edition, and it is resulting in following error:

**Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Apex Classes**

Would this error still appear if I install the package in a purchased Professional Edition (not trial)?

Comment: Is your package certified/security reviewed? I seem to recall that being a requirement before any managed package with apex code can be installed in a PE org. I think in the general case, Apex is only accessible in EE and above, or dev.

Comment: No its not certified/security reviewed (what are the steps to do so...). I just created a managed package, uploaded it and with the "Installation URL" I tried installing it on a trial professional edition and it resulted in above error. It seems security review is part of above process, which I have missed. Right?

Answer (score 2):

As abeyer said you need to have your package put through the Security Review and it be Certified before you can install in Professional Edition Orgs.

There are 2 reasons for this:

- Only trusted Partners are certified to install in PE org. This makes sure that all packages listed on AppExchange with PE access do not contain any malicious code
- It avoids people using managed packages to circumvent the limitations of their edition.

Here's the link to where you can get started: http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Security_Review

Comment: No its not certified/security reviewed (what are the steps to do so...). I just created a managed package, uploaded it and with the "Installation URL" I tried installing it on a trial professional edition and it resulted in above error. It seems security review is part of above process, which I have missed. Right?